# Get filename after ajax uploading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use jqueryForm and imgAreaSelect plugins for upload an image, crop it with imgAreaSelect plugin and then save. The problem is i don't know how to get file name after uploading. Sure i know how it being made and know the source, but can't access variable from upload php script.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".uploadform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#viewimage',
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                $("#viewimage").html('Uploading...');
            },
            success: function () {

                $('img').imgAreaSelect({
                aspectRatio: '166:90',
                minHeight: 90,
                minWidth: 166,
                onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
                    $('input[name="x1"]').val(selection.x1);
                    $('input[name="y1"]').val(selection.y1);
                    $('input[name="x2"]').val(selection.x2);
                    $('input[name="y2"]').val(selection.y2);            
                    $('input[name="width"]').val(selection.x2-selection.x1);
                    $('input[name="height"]').val(selection.y2-selection.y1);     
                    $('input[name="source"]').val($(this));                     
                }});

            }
        });
    });
```

So the question is how i can get variable from script that used by ajax to access source to image uploaded?

UPD: 
Php script:

```
   $imagename = md5(uniqid().time()).".".$extension;
         $tmp = $_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'];
         if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $filepath . $imagename)) {
         echo '<img class="preview" alt="" src="'.$filepath.'/'. 
         $imagename .'" />';
```

Comment: Please post the php script. And you should be able to find any files in the $_FILES[] variable for your php script.

Comment: Posted the php script in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

the name will be in

```
$_FILES['imagefile']['name']
```

Comment: No, there is no name in such variable.

Comment: Im pretty sure there will be if the name of the input was 'imagefile' and it was uploaded. This is coming from W3. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Well this is something that helps me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".uploadform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#viewimage',
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            $("#viewimage").html('Uploading...');
//          showRequest;            
        },
        success: function () {
        $('img').imgAreaSelect({
//          showResponse();
            aspectRatio: '166:90',
            minHeight: 90,
            minWidth: 166,  
            onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
                $('input[name="x1"]').val(selection.x1);
                $('input[name="y1"]').val(selection.y1);
                $('input[name="x2"]').val(selection.x2);
                $('input[name="y2"]').val(selection.y2);            
                $('input[name="width"]').val(selection.x2-selection.x1);
                $('input[name="height"]').val(selection.y2-selection.y1);       
                $('input[name="source"]').val($('img').attr( 'src' ));
            }});

        }
    });
});
```